# Simple derangement algorithm (secret santa)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algorithms, derangements

> In combinatorial mathematics, a derangement is a permutation of the
> elements of a set, such that no element appears in its original
> position. - from Wikipedia

A real example might be a secret santa draw where each person is randomly assigned another person who they have to buy a present, and everyone should be assigned only once to someone (but not themselves).

Anyway, I saw a lot of algorithms that just try random combinations until no "collisions" occur. My question is can we use a trivial solution where we map each element to the next, and the last one to the first:
$$(a_1, a_2,...a_n) \implies (a_2, a_3, ..., a_n, a_1) $$ However, my idea is to first shuffle the elements or take a permutation, and then map them as previously explained.

*Example:*

1. Take ANY permutation, collisions 3 and 4 are fine

$$
(1, 2, 3, 4) \implies (2, 1, 3, 4)
$$

2. And then we apply the "trivial" mapping:

$$
(2, 1, 3, 4) \implies (1, 3, 4, 2)
$$

3. Reverse shuffle to finally get:

$$
(1, 2, 3, 4) \implies (3, 1, 4, 2)
$$

Wouldn't this work faster then just "guessing", since we take any random permutation without discarding it? Is there any bias?

Comment: When $ n \geq 5$ is odd, there are permutations where compositions with the "trivial" shift-by-1 mapping $\sigma$ doesn't yield a derangement. E.g. With $(1, 4, 2, 5, 3)$, $\sigma^k$ has $k-1$ as a fixed point. So unfortunately, your idea would not work for any permutation.

Comment: There is a [numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kC5k5QBqcc) on this topic that you might appreciate

Comment: Here's a solution that seems to be somewhat in the spirit of what you're going for. Let $\sigma$ denote the cyclic permutation $\pmatrix{1&2&\cdots&n-1&n\\2&3&\cdots&n&1}$. Of course, $\sigma$ is a derangement. Let $\pi$ denote a random permutation. The permutation $\pi \circ \sigma \circ \pi^{-1}$ will be a (randomly selected) cycle of order $n$, which is guaranteed to be a derangement. We don't have the potential to reach every possible derangement, but for the purposes of secret santa I suspect that this is "good enough".

Comment: @CalvinLin oh..but at least for even $n$ it's fine?

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks, can't believe I didn't look it up - of course they have a video on it xd.

Comment: @AndrijaRadica For even $n$, given any permutation, you can eventually rotate it around so that we have a derangement. You can try to prove that claim.